# How can we translate the dynamic value

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

In my form am using this to display multiple error messages so am unable to translate this messages with the help of the translator

```html
<span * ngIf="formErrors.giftCardNumber" class="invalid-feedback" >
            {{formErrors.giftCardNumber | translate }}
</span>
```

so here .giftCardNumber have multilpe validation error how can i translate this using ngx translate.

```js
this.stepOneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    giftCardNumber: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]\d*$/),
        Validators.minLength(16),
        Validators.maxLength(16)
    ])
});
```

below method is helping me to get the error messages

```js
logValidationErrors(group: FormGroup = this.stepOneForm): void {
    Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {

        const abstractControl = group.get(key);
        if (abstractControl instanceof FormGroup) {

            this.logValidationErrors(abstractControl);
        } else {


            this.formErrors[key] = '';

            if (abstractControl && !abstractControl.valid
                && (abstractControl.touched || abstractControl.dirty)) {

                // const messages = (this.translateService.currentLang === 'fr') ? this.validationMessagesSpn[key] : this.validationMessages[key];
                const messages = this.validationMessages[key];
                for (const errorKey in abstractControl.errors) {
                    if (errorKey) {
                        this.formErrors[key] = messages[errorKey] + ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and i have defined

```js
    formErrors = {
        'giftCardNumber': '',
        'pin': '',
        'zipCode': '',
        'state': '',
        'recaptchaReactive': ''
    }

    validationMessages = {
        'giftCardNumber': {
            'required': 'Gift Card Number is mandatory',
            'pattern': 'Please provide only numbers.',
            'minlength': 'Minimum length allowed 16',
            'maxlength': 'Maxlength length allowed 16'


        }
    }
```

In my form am using this to display multiple error messages

```html
< span * ngIf="formErrors.giftCardNumber" class="invalid-feedback" >
    {{formErrors.giftCardNumber | translate }}
</span>
```

so here .giftCardNumber have multilpe validation error how can i translate this using ngx translate.

```js
this.stepOneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    giftCardNumber: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]\d*$/),
        Validators.minLength(16),
        Validators.maxLength(16)

    ])
});
```

below method is helping me to get the error messages

```js
logValidationErrors(group: FormGroup = this.stepOneForm): void {
    Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {

        const abstractControl = group.get(key);
        if (abstractControl instanceof FormGroup) {

            this.logValidationErrors(abstractControl);
        } else {


            this.formErrors[key] = '';

            if (abstractControl && !abstractControl.valid
                && (abstractControl.touched || abstractControl.dirty)) {

                // const messages = (this.translateService.currentLang === 'fr') ? this.validationMessagesSpn[key] : this.validationMessages[key];
                const messages = this.validationMessages[key];
                for (const errorKey in abstractControl.errors) {
                    if (errorKey) {
                        this.formErrors[key] = messages[errorKey] + ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and i have difined

```js
    formErrors = {
        'giftCardNumber': '',
        'pin': '',
        'zipCode': '',
        'state': '',
        'recaptchaReactive': ''
    }

    validationMessages = {
        'giftCardNumber': {
            'required': 'Gift Card Number is mandatory',
            'pattern': 'Please provide only numbers.',
            'minlength': 'Minimum length allowed 16',
            'maxlength': 'Maxlength length allowed 16'


        }
    }`
```

i have tried in couple of ways 
const messages = (this.translateService.currentLang === 'fr') ? this.validationMessagesSpn[key] : this.validationMessages[key];
am changing the validationMessages to validationMessagesSpn i can able to achieve the out by translating but it does not change instantly as we switch the language , i need to again enter something then this will be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to register these error messages in your i18n files. NGX translate doesn't work without i18n files.
2. Then in your component

```js
validationMessages = {
        'giftCardNumber': {
            'required': 'error.gift_card_number_required',
            'pattern': 'error.gift_card_number_only',
            'minlength': 'error.gift_card_number_minlength',
            'maxlength': 'error.gift_card_number_maxlength'


        }
 }
```

Then in your i18n, en.json for example. add these:

```
{
 "error.gift_card_number_required": "blablabla",
 …
 …
}
```

Comment: Thanks,i already have the i18n folder within that i have two json en.json and sp.json,i tried what you suggested but that shows error as is ''error.gift_card_number_required',it is not reading from the .json file.

Comment: Did you set up the translation Environment in app Module?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Delete your defined objects and put translations in files en.json like:

```
'gift-card-number': {
            'required': 'Gift Card Number is mandatory',
            'pattern': 'Please provide only numbers.',
            'minlength': 'Minimum length allowed 16',
            'maxlength': 'Maxlength length allowed 16'
}
```

then make function:

```
getGiftCardNumberErrors() {
    return this.GiftCardNumber.hasError('required') ? this.translateService.get('girt-card-number-errors.required') :
    this.GiftCardNumber.hasError('pattern') ? this.translateService.get('girt-card-number-errors.pattern') :
    this.GiftCardNumber.hasError('minLength') ? this.translateService.get('girt-card-number-errors.minlength') : 
    this.GiftCardNumber.hasError('maxLength') ? this.translateService.get('girt-card-number-errors.maxlength') :'';
  }
```

And template:

```
<div *ngIf="giftCardNumber.invalid && !''">{{getGiftCardNumerErrors()}}</div>
```